# Require different php files depending on a selected option

Tags: php, html

I'm quite new to php, and I was thinking about making languages change on a website by requiring a file with variables depending on a selected language.

For now, its just 2 languages, but will be more. Variables with blocks in English are stored in content.php file, and variables in Russian - in ru.php.

Here is my html form:

```html
<div id="language">
  <form method="post" action="lang.php" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  <select name="language">
    <option value="en">en</option>
    <option value="ru">ru</option>
  </select>
 </form>
</div>
```

And here is the PHP I was trying to use (but no success):

```html
$option = $_POST['language'];


    if ($option == 'ru')
      {
        require('ru.php');
                     
        }


   if ($option =='en')
      {
       require('content.php');
        }
```

Please let me know if you know how I can make it work.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: You're going to struggle with this as your user will have to submit the form continually to have the `$_POST` variable for the language set. If I were you, I'd look at storing the value in a session and including your language files based off that

Comment: @Darren We have no idea what's in ru.php or content.php. We also have no idea what's not working.

Comment: The better option is on change select box set language variable to cookie and based on cookie value include your language file. This option will work for your whole site

Comment: Inside content.php and ru.php only variables, they work fine. I make the check and changing the content with : ($check = 10;
if ($check < 10) {
    require('ru.php');
}
else if ($check === 10) {

  require('content.php');
}

Comment: After I moved onchange="this.form.submit()" to select, submission started to work. But it goes to the blank page of lang.php

Answer (score 4):

For persistence of the user's language choice throughout your website, storing their preference for a period of time, you have 3 main options:

1. **COOKIES**
2. **$_SESSION** variables
3. **Database** lookups

I like $_SESSIONs for a variety of reasons. Learn [more about sessions here](https://phpocean.com/tutorials/back-end/learn-how-to-use-php-sessions/56).

The following PHP would have to be required at the top of every page (let's call it `requires.php`). It could look like this:

---

**requires.php**

```
$timeout = 60*60*3; // 3 hour maximum session timeout
session_start([
    'name'            => 'my_groovy_session',
    'gc_maxlifetime'  => $timeout, // server session lifetime
    'cookie_lifetime' => $timeout, // client cookie lifetime
    ]);

// set language if empty
if (empty($_SESSION['lang'])) $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';

// choose file
if (is_file('languages/'. $_SESSION['lang'] .'.php')) {
    require_once 'languages/'. $_SESSION['lang'] .'.php';
} else {
    require_once 'languages/en.php';
}
```

---

Your `lang.php` would just be something like this:

**lang.php**

```
$_SESSION['lang'] = $_POST['language'];
```

---

This method adds all the translations into the same directory. They could look something like this:

**en.php**

```
$words = [
    'welcome' => 'Welcome to so-and-so',
    'email'   => 'Please email us at blah@blah.com',
    'close'   => 'Close',
];
```

---

**ru.php**

```
$words = [
    'welcome' => 'Добро пожаловать в такое-то',
    'email'   => 'Пожалуйста, напишите нам на blah@blah.com',
    'close'   => 'Закрыть',
];
```

---

And then in any PHP file that used `requires.php`, you could then output the words in the user's preferred language:

```
echo $words['welcome'];
```

Just be sure leave the array `keys` themselves (welcome, email, close) un-translated.

---

Note: The above uses the short array syntax `[]` for arrays. If you're using PHP version < 5.4 you'll need to use `array()`.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Below code structure works fine. You can add your required files to make it work.

**form.html**

I have changed the position of `onchange="this.form.submit()"`

```
<div id="language">
  <form method="post" action="lang.php" >
    <select name="language" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="en">en</option>
    <option value="ru">ru</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

**lang.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$option = $_POST['language'];

if ($option == 'ru')
  {
    require('ru.php');
    echo($word);                 
  }

if ($option =='en')
  {
    require('en.php');
    echo($word); 
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**en.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$word = "i am english";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**ru.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$word = "i am russian";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! After moving onchange="this.form.submit()" to select, submission started to work. But it goes to a blank page and shows only echoed variables.

Comment: Yes, this code will echo "i am english" or "i am russian". Do you see a blank page in lang.php ?

Comment: No, I added echo($title) instead of your variable and I saw a blank(not entirely blank, with a text) page with the title content. I meant that I wanted to change $title (and every other variable) on index.php, but I can't figure out how to do so yet

Comment: Two notes: 1) The opening/closing <html> and <body> tags in `en.php` and `ru.php` already exist in `lang.php`, which would cause problems. 2) This approach still doesn't store the users' language selection ... those two files would only be used once after the dropdown selection, which doesn't seem to match the OP's goal.